# How to use tabs OOTB in hybris on mine custom tabs?

Tags: components, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to create my custom tabs in hybris. I saw OOTB example for product details page. There has TabsSlot and for cmsComponents(&componentRef) use TabPanelContainer which contains 3 jsps with JspIncludeComponents. In my way I want to have in my custom page templete MyTabs for Slot and inside it I have again 3 jsps, but when load the page the content inside body is ok, but in head looks bad. [image]

There don't has css classes , why is that and how can I make it?
The situaton is, I have 3 tabs for example, 2 of them I don't want to be editable in smartedit ( to be jspincludecomponent ) , but for other 1 I want to be custom component and will be editable from smatedit.

In cms-content.impex I created this.

```
INSERT_UPDATE JspIncludeComponent; $contentCV[unique = true]; uid[unique = true]; name               ; page                 ; actions(uid, $contentCV); &componentRef
                                 ;                          ; Contact           ; Contact            ; contact.jsp          ;                         ; Contact
                                 ;                          ; MySupportTickets  ; My Support Tickets ; mySupportTickets.jsp ;                         ; MySupportTickets
                                 ;                          ; Faq               ; Faq                ; faqTab.jsp           ;                         ; Faq

INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlot; $contentCV[unique = true]; uid[unique = true]          ; name                                  ; active; cmsComponents(&componentRef)
                         ;                          ; Tabs                     ; Body Content Slot for Support and FAQ ; true  ; FAQTabsContainer


INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlotForPage; $contentCV[unique = true]; uid[unique = true]          ; position[unique = true]; page(uid, $contentCV)[unique = true][default = 'supportAndFAQPage']; contentSlot(uid, $contentCV)[unique = true]
                                ;                          ; BodyContent-support-and-faq ; Tabs                ;                                                                    ; Tabs

INSERT_UPDATE CMSTabParagraphContainer; $contentCV[unique = true]; uid[unique = true]; name              ; visible; simpleCMSComponents(uid, $contentCV); &componentRef
                                      ;                          ; FAQTabsContainer  ; Tab container ; true   ; Contact,MySupportTickets,Faq  ; FAQTabsContainer
```

also I have one page which will use these jspincludecomponents inside it as `<cms:PageSlot position="Tabs"/>`

In jsps I use for head tabs `<tabshead>....</tabshead>` and for body `<tabsbody>...</tabsbody>` . The body looks ok with the html but header tabs looks bad. I don't know what is the reason

Comment: You are very likely going to have to provide some code to get help on this forum.  SO is about assisting in coding problems.

Comment: I update my question